# Message file \ORANT\DBS\FMCUS.MSB not found Oracle Forms 6i

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, registry, oracleforms

I install Oracle Developer Suite 6i on Windows 10 Professional 64-bit, but when i run form builder, its give the error **\ORANT\DBS\FMCUS.MSB** not found. but when i search this file in in installed 6i directory this file is exist there, when i google this error, i found a solution: its suggest me to run the form builder in compatibility mode of windows XP service pack 2. but still its show the same error given below:
[Message file \ORANT\DBS\FMCUS.MSB not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eivp7.png)

Kindly suggest me what should i do to get rid from this error. Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

Typically errors like this mean the software does not know precisely where it is installed.  A couple of options that *might* resolve this (I say might because that is some very old software you've got there).

1. Try setting ORACLE_HOME as an environment variable
2. Look in the registry for the the key which nominates where Forms is installed and set ORACLE_HOME there.
3. Create a batch file which sets ORACLE_HOME and then launches Forms

Answer (score 1):

If you still have an old installation of Oracle Developer Suite. Look for the *keys* like :

- `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OH155385982]` and
  `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Oracle\KEY_OH267560998]`.
- *Export* them as `Key_ODS64.reg` and `Key_ODS64_Wow.reg`, respectively.
- Go to your new installation's machine and *Import* by double-clicking.